# How can I hide WebRequest redirections from the rest of chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use chrome's experimental WebRequest URI to do resource translation - so that URLs link to different back end resources than they would outwardly do.  In Firefox, I'm used to registering a new protocol handler, so that:

```
myscheme:user_prefs
```

actually is connected to some webserver like so:

```
https://myhost/prefs?token=bla
```

I'm sort of lost, is there a way to do something similar in Chrome?

Comment: There's some HTML5 API. I think. But I don't know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the WebRequest API (make sure you're on the Beta channel or higher):

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
  if (details.url.indexOf("myscheme")!=0)
    return;
  var options = details.url.substr(details.url.indexof(":"));
  return { redirectUrl: "https://myhost/prefs?" + options };
},{},["blocking"]);
```

...and that's completely untested code. Feel free to test it, debug it, fix it, whatever... but keep in mind you'll need to ask for some permissions: `"webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>"`

Comment: This looks good, and we did get this to work - my question is more about hiding these webrequests from the frontend user.  When I do this, the url https://myost/prefs?bla shows up in the URL bar.  Is there a way to change that?

Comment: You can try and use the navigator.registerProtocolHandler API but that doesn't work consistently for me, and requires you to nag the user. I don't even know if it does what you're looking for - so if that doesn't work there's no way I can think of short of writing a NPAPI plugin.

Comment: I've never heard of the registerProtocolHandler - is that intended for use in plugins or for the whole browser?  I'll have to play around it (do you have any favorite resource on it?).  Also - I've looked at NPAPI plugins, but they seem to be designed just to produce content for a square of screen in a page, is there some way around that?

Comment: You can make NPAPI plugins hidden, and they can do stuff on the client's computer. I don't have much experience with them.
There isn't really one resource that's suitable for registerProtocolHandler - just Google it, I guess. Again, it doesn't work for me, so you should probably try to just find another way to do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I can only really find information about creating flash-like plugins (that render somewhere, basically).  Where can I find out about NPAPI plugins changing the resource loading behavior of the browser they are embedded in?  I can see how to make requests, but not how to intercept them from the client.  Also, since they're usually hosted in their own process, it doesn't seem really possible to do it by injecting my own code into the browser in question.  Any ideas?

Comment: Erm, unfortunately I'm not qualified to speak about NPAPI plugins (or anything else for that matter :) but you can set them to have a width/height of 0...

I really think that unless you absolutely need to (why?) you *really shouldn't try to do this*... it's too difficult for little gain.

I would just redirect to one of your extension's pages so that teh URL won't show, and put whatever you want in an iframe from there on.

Comment: "one of your extension's pages" - this seems harder than it should be - am I missing something?  How can I show one of my extension's pages with a random URL in the URL bar?

Comment: No, if you load an extension page, its url won't show at all...

Replace the redirect url with `chrome.extension.getURL("local_url.html")`

Comment: I see that it doesn't show any URL at all - is there any way to get to not change the URL (in this case, leave whatever was there?)  Or to set it to something arbitrary?

Comment: No (as far as I know), BUT if you _reallyreallyreally_ want to, you _can_ inject code into Chrome via a NPAPI plugin; you can get started with that with Chrome Toolbox's code at http://code.google.com/p/chrome-toolbox/source/browse/ (but that's way overboard and you're going to have to ask the user for permission to access their computer).